# Create view form that updates attributes - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I currently have a basic controller and model that creates a Subscriber with the normal attributes(name, email, phone, etc...), but I also have a `visit` attribute on the Subscriber. So I have a form that's rendered with the "new" action and save the input with the create action. << VERY BASIC >>  The new feature I want to implement is create a new form that takes in only a phone_number and when the number is entered it update the visit attribute on the subscriber that that corresponds with that number. right now I'm struggling trying to figure this out with just one controller. I'll  show my current controller and hopefully that will help for clarity.

CONTROLLER

```
class SubscribersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @subscriber = Subscriber.all
  end

  def new
    @subscriber = Subscriber.new
  end

  def create
    @subscriber = Subscriber.create(subscriber_params)
    if @subscriber.save
      flash[:success] = "Subscriber Has Been successfully Created"
      redirect_to new_subscriber_path(:subscriber)
    else
      render "new"
    end
  end

  def visit
    @subscriber = Subscriber.find_by_phone_number(params[:phone_number])
    if @subscriber
      @subscriber.visit += 1
      @subscriber.save
      redirect_to subscribers_visits_new_path(:subscriber)
    else
      render "new"
    end
  end
end
```

As you can see in the visit action I'm trying to implement this feature but I'm not sure where to go from here?

Comment: So basically you want to increment the visit count for each phone number when visited?

Comment: Have you set the route for the `visit` action?

Comment: I haven't set the route yet but I'm more wondering how to set up the controller? @mlovic

Comment: It looks fine for the most part. You'll probably want to normalize the phone number (remove spaces, dashes, etc.). Not sure what path `subscribers_visits_new_path` is supposed to represent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose your `search` page has a form where you type the number you want to search for. And the request comes to `visit` action, where you'll increment the +1 to the visit count and then show the details of the number(subscriber).

```
def visit
  #Comes request from search action
  @subscriber = Subscriber.find_by_phone_number(params[:phone_number])
  if @subscriber
    @subscriber.visit += 1
    @subscriber.save
    redirect_to subscriber_path(@subscriber)
    #It will show the details
  else
    flash[:alert] = "Didn't find with that number. Search again."
    render :action => :search
  end
end
```

> Update:
>
> Search logic

```
def search
  #will render search.html.erb by convention
end
```

Inside search.html.erb

```
<%= form_tag({controller: "subscribers", action: "visit"}, method: "get") do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :phone_number %>
  <%= submit_tag "Submit" %>
<% end %>
```

So this will send params to `visit` action, and after incrementing it will render show method. Hope this helps. Let me know if there is anything.

Comment: That's perfect, do you know how to set up the search page? that's the part I'm struggling with